# ClassNotFoundException when package Spring Boot Application with native-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graalvm

I try to build a native executables on win 10 use SpringBoot 3.0 (include Spring Test) and Graalvm. I packaged my project with `native-maven-plugin` but failed.
How do I fix it?

JDK version: 17.0.6

Graalvm version:  GraalVM CE 22.3.1

Pacakge command:

```
mvn -Pnative package
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The error log:

```
Failures (1):
  JUnit Jupiter:DemoApplicationTests
    ClassSource [className = 'com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests', filePosition = null]
    => java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:113)
       org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
       org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223)
       org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211)
       org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191)
       [...]
       Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils
         org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:113)
         org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
         org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223)
         org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211)
         org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191)
         [...]
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load class for @org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
       org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.loadWebAppConfigurationClass(BootstrapUtils.java:213)
       org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.<clinit>(BootstrapUtils.java:63)
       [...]
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
       java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1132)
       org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:283)
       org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.loadWebAppConfigurationClass(BootstrapUtils.java:209)
       [...]

Test run finished after 166 ms
[         2 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         2 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         1 containers successful ]
[         1 containers failed     ]
[         1 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

Comment: you do not need to provide native profile, it is coming from parent.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil You are right. I remove the part of test execution, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to provide native profile, it is coming from parent. Example pom below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

https://start.spring.io/ is the main location for starting a new spring boot project.