# Spring project migration to GraalVM native build - JmxMBeanServer error

Tags: java, spring, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to migrate a quite complex spring project into GraalVM native build. I encountered the first issue which is:

```
Fatal error: org.graalvm.compiler.debug.GraalError: org.graalvm.compiler.debug.GraalError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: Detected a MBean server in the image heap. This is currently not supported, but could be changed in the future. Management beans are registered in many global caches that would need to be cleared and properly re-built at image build time. Class of disallowed object: com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer Try to avoid initializing the class that stores a MBean server or a MBean in a static field
The culprit object has been instantiated by the 'com.azure.core.util.Configuration' class initializer with the following trace:
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.<init>(JmxMBeanServer.java:225)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.newMBeanServer(JmxMBeanServer.java:1437)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerBuilder.newMBeanServer(MBeanServerBuilder.java:110)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:329)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:231)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:192)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:487)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:139)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:642)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:713)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:735)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:260)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:197)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:32)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:422)
    at com.azure.core.util.logging.ClientLogger.<init>(ClientLogger.java:100)
    at com.azure.core.util.logging.ClientLogger.<init>(ClientLogger.java:66)
    at com.azure.core.util.logging.ClientLogger.<init>(ClientLogger.java:56)
    at com.azure.core.util.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:258)
```

I've tried to use: `--initialize-at-build-time=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer` but there's not change with this flag.

Plugin config is as below:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.28</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- imageName is used to set the name of the generated binary file -->
                    <imageName>${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <!-- mainClass is used to specify the path to the main method class -->
                    <mainClass>com.example.Server</mainClass>
                    <buildArgs>
                        --no-fallback
                        --trace-object-instantiation=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer
                        --initialize-at-build-time=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-native</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

- Spring Boot: 3.2.1
- Java: 21
- GraalVM: 21.0.1
- native-maven-plugin: 0.9.28

Comment: why do you migrate?

Comment: you are not suppose to add [native maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75667618/175554). If your project is very complex it is not easy to find the reason from this information, can you share a reproducer ?